# Does a holomorphic $f$ exist satisfying these conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

We need to determine if there exists a holomorphic function
$$f: \Delta \to \mathbb{C},$$ where $$\Delta = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| <1\}$$ is such that 
$$\frac{d^n f}{d z^n} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)= 2^n n! $$

My intuition is that there should not be such a function. My idea was to assume that $$f(z) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n z^n,$$ and to determine a recursion relation between the coefficients $a_n$ by substituting the information about the derivative above. I suspect that the coefficients should not converge to zero. However, I struggled trying to show this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Cauchy's formula. For a circle $C$ around the origin with radius $1/2<r<1$, and $n$ large enough, we have $2^nn!=|f^{(n)}(1/n)|=\frac{n!}{2\pi}|\int_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-1/n)^{n+1}}dz|\leq n!\max_C|f||r-1/n|^{-(n+1)}\leq n!\max_C|f| r^{-(n+1)}$. But $2^n$ grows faster than $r^{-(n+1)}$. You could use [Cauchy's estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Consequences) directly. The above is the argument passing through the proof of Cauchy's estimates.

Comment: @flan why didn't post it as an answer?

Comment: @flan where does the last inequality come from? isn't it that $|r-1/n|^{-(n+1)} \ge r^{-(n+1)}$ instead?

Comment: That's right. Just ignore the last inequality. It is not important to get the contradiction anyway.

Comment: @flan ah ok that makes sense now, thank you!